# XCode 'Fix It' hell

Tags: c++, xcode

I am trying to use XCode to write a very simple console app. It really only had one requirement that I can link to a static library which I built from source code that I downloaded from GitHub. After spending a few hours yesterday trying to figure out the peculiarities of using a static library in XCode I finally got that working. Today while working on the code I clicked on the XCode 'Fix It' button in one of the errors I had in the code and now I am stuck with this modal dialog that says I can't save the file string. I don't want to save the file string. I think XCode is trying to make a change to one of the standard C++ header files. I just want to build my project but every time I do the modal shown below pops up twice and I have to dismiss it before the build completes. I thought I would be able to Undo, or command+z or just close the string file that XCode keeps wanting to update but i can't find that file open anywhere in the editor. Anyway I'm giving up on using XCode for working in C++. It's a mess and wastes way too much time. If you just need to do simple C++ stuff on a Mac you are probably better off using a makefile and textedit. But, I'm just curious about this one last problem

[image: xcode pain]

Comment: LOL I can't even quit out of xcode because that modal keeps blocking the Quit menu action. I guess I'll just terminate the process.

Comment: Seems like the "fix" involved modifying the `<string>` header which of course is readonly for anyone lacking administrator rights. The thing about functionality like "Fix it" is that you need to check, if the suggested fix is actually appropriate or if it's just a random suggestion of the IDE since it cannot pin down the actual issue. Btw: I've also seen IDEs highlight errors in code that's actually perfectly fine simply because the code analyzer of the IDE didn't implement the latest language features.